# Run test with accessible private field in tested class

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection

I have some class with constant to test:

```
public class SomeClass {
     private static final String SOME_CONST = "blabla";
```

And I have to use it in test, so I make (with Spring ReflectionUtils and java.lang native arsenal) smth like:

```
findField(SomeClass.class, "SOME_CONST").setAccessible(true);
```

or

```
makeAccessible(findField(SomeClass.class, "SOME_CONST"));
```

Running test

```
@Test
public void someTest() throws Exception {
    String s = SomeClass.SOME_CONST;
```

I see my Intellij Idea stops running with error related with trying to access private field. Suppose I should use some kind of `@SuppressWarnings` or how to solve such an issue better?

Comment: for private method testing you can use EasyMock and power mock

Comment: Using PowerMock or EasyMock fits better for another case, at first, and it's a first sign of bad design, at second - we don't use such a libraries for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing private methods/fields is usually sign of bad design.
If you don't mind to show it around, set it public or put a getter to retrieve that variable, since it's final you should not have any trouble unless it has sensitive data or it's a mutable class (not the case of a String).
Or using your approach, do

```
Field field = TargetClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
field.setAccessible(true);
String someConst = (String) field.get(new SomeClass());
```

following [this hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-to-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes)

Comment: Totally agree with you - I would mark constant field as public too. Unfortunately I work with legacy code and it would be better don't touch sources.

Comment: It's up to you to evaluate if it's too risky, in the worst case you can use the reflection approach

Comment: Actually I use reflection approach :) I just don't want to use extra code for setting some fields of test class to values from tested class, I'm trying to do it gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

As were mentioned above we can (or even should) change `private` fields of tested class to `public`, but in case you are not able to do so you can use my soulution (I tried to avoid extra fields in test class, but nobody suggested solution to my question):

```
private String EXTRA_FIELD_TO_HOLD_CONSTANT_VALUE_FROM_TESTED_CLASS;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception { 
    EXTRA_FIELD_TO_HOLD_CONSTANT_VALUE_FROM_TESTED_CLASS = 
        getPrivateStringConstantValue("SOME_CONST");
}

private String getPrivateStringConstantValue(String fieldName) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Field field = findField(CtcFraudIPAddressListServiceImpl.class, fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    return field.get(testedService).toString();
}
```